# cannot inspect "if let" variables in gdb

Tags: debugging, rust, gdb

I'm having trouble inspecting variables set by if-let statements, for instance the following main.rs in a freshly created cargo project named "iflet-rust":

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Stuff;
fn maybe() -> Option<Stuff> {
    Some(Stuff {})
}
fn main() {
    if let Some(first) = maybe() {
        println!("first {:?}", first); // line 8, cannot inspect 'first' here
    }

    let maybe_stuff = maybe();
    if maybe_stuff.is_some() {
        let second = maybe_stuff.unwrap();
        println!("second {:?}", second); // no problem here
    }
}
```

Then running `cargo build` and `rust-gdb target/debug/iflet-rust`

```
Reading symbols from target/debug/iflet-rust...
(gdb) b main.rs:8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x83f1: file src/main.rs, line 8.
(gdb) b main.rs:14
Breakpoint 2 at 0x848b: file src/main.rs, line 14.
(gdb) r
Starting program: iflet-rust/target/debug/iflet-rust 

Breakpoint 1, iflet_rust::main () at src/main.rs:8
8               println!("first {:?}", first); // cannot inspect 'first' here
(gdb) p first
No symbol 'first' in current context
(gdb) info locals
No locals.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
first Stuff

Breakpoint 2, iflet_rust::main () at src/main.rs:14
14              println!("second {:?}", second); // no problem here
(gdb) info locals
second = iflet_rust::Stuff
maybe_stuff = core::option::Option::Some
```

Is this a know limitation or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you running `rust-gdb` or straight `gdb`? Try the former if you aren't. Also ensure you're compiling in debug mode.

Comment: I'm running `rust-gdb target/debug/iflet-rust`. My `Cargo.toml` is freshly created from `cargo new iflet-rust` and I'm compiling using `cargo build` which should be with debug enabled. I'm able to inspect other fields so I suspect it is.

Comment: Does printing locals otherwise work for you? Are you compiling in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell it's only in the if-let that I'm having troubles. I've edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue in the compiler, updating to Rust from 1.60 to 1.63 fixes the problem.

I shouldn't have limited my search to open issues, unfortunate timing.

See https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/97799